# Powershell remoting does not have the correct permissions

Tags: powershell, cross-domain, powershell-remoting

On the non-domain server `SERVER` I have a local administrator account `USER`.

On the domain client machine I am running as a domain user.

Using the following code I attempt to view all services on `SERVER`

```
$cred = Get-Credential "SERVER\USER"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER -ScriptBlock {Get-Service} -Credential $cred
```

However, I receive the following error

> Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Yet, if I RDP to `SERVER` as `USER`, I can manually open a Powershell window and run `Get-Service` without any issues. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When remoting cross-domain, the remote command/session will not run with administrative rights. Even though you're connecting as a local admin, the resulting PSSession will not be elevated.

To fix this, you need to set the registry key **LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy** located in ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System*** to 1. See [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016) for more details